# PHP - find all all files within directory that match certain string and put in array

Tags: php, arrays, file

I have a directory of images on a server that customers have uploaded. I need to be able to get all files that match a certain string or item code and put them inside an array. Filenames and extensions can always vary but each file will always have an 8 digit item code in the filename. So for instance say in my directory i have:

```
/images/

62115465.jpg
62115465-02.jpg
62115465-07.jpg
13452766.png
56773392.jpeg
56773392-avatar.jpg
```

I want to be able to pull out all the files that match the 8 digit item code so:

```
//all images that have 62115465 in the file name would give me

62115465.jpg
62115465-02.jpg
62115465-07.jpg

//or all images that have 56773392 in the file name would give me

56773392.jpeg
56773392-avatar.jpg
```

and then want them in an array like so:

```
$all_files = array(
  '62115465.jpg',
  '62115465-02.jpg',
  '62115465-07.jpg'
);
```

I tried using the `glob()` function as below which can match some files like the `62115465.jpg` but doesnt pick up the 2 other files with the `-02` and `-07` tags

```
$files = glob('62115465.'.*');
```

Comment: Did you try removing the `.`?

Comment: This should sort it for you, `$files = glob('62115465*.*');` it will match anything starting with the number and with any ext.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
glob('62115465*');
```

note the removal of the `.`. glob() essentially replicates doing something like `dir *.txt` at a command prompt.

Answer (score 2):

I know this question was answered already, but to the novice/intermediate coder, or anyone new to the glob() function (*AHEM* *ME* *COUGH*), it's pretty unclear what's going on here. So, here's a full script that I cobbled together to do pretty much the same thing the OP asked for- search through a directory for all files beginning with the target prefix and add them to an array.:

```
<?php
$imgs = array();
$dir =  $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/path/to/your/images';
$prefix = 'your-prefix_string-_-';
chdir($dir);
$matches = glob("$prefix*");
if(is_array($matches) && !empty($matches)){
    foreach($matches as $match){
        $imgs[] = $match;
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this,

```
 $files = glob('62115465.*');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this-

```
$files = glob("[^62115465]*.*);
```

Or like this:

```
$files = glob("62115465*.*);
```